# How to display column name and column comment, when try DML

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm try use DML operations on table, when insert or update. I need to show column name and column comment when the operation failed. For example code:

```
CREATE TABLE test_test(col1 VARCHAR2(10), col2 VARCHAR2(100) not null);
DECLARE
  ex_insert_null EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(ex_insert_null, -1400);
  ex_value_too_large EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(ex_value_too_large, -12899);
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO test_test
    (col1
    ,col2)
    SELECT CASE
             WHEN LEVEL = 8 THEN
              (LEVEL + 1) || 'qqqqqqqqqqqq'
             ELSE
              (LEVEL + 2) || 'qqq'
           END AS col1
          ,CASE
             WHEN LEVEL = 7 THEN
              NULL
             ELSE
              (LEVEL + 3) || 'wwwwwww'
           END AS col2
      FROM dual
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10;
    COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN ex_insert_null THEN
    ROLLBACK;
    dbms_output.put_line('ex_insert_null at ' || ' ' /* || column_name || ' ' || column_comment */);
  WHEN ex_value_too_large THEN
    ROLLBACK;
    dbms_output.put_line('ex_value_too_large at ' || ' ' /* || column_name || ' ' || column_comment */);
END;
/
```

Comment: You are attempting to override existing Oracle exceptions. Given that those exceptions already give the column names - and execute a rollback when they are hurled -  this code is the very definition of an exercise in pointlessness. So, what are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: I try to display column name(metadata col1) on a display, when exception ex_insert_null is raise or show column name(metadata col2), when ex_value_too_large is raise. I did not find that these exceptions already exist. Write as they are called please or show a piece of code how to correctly raise these exceptions.

Comment: The numbers you have used in the pragma declarations are the ORA ERRNO for those exceptions. So how could you not know they exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As APC has pointed out, you could use "existing Oracle exceptions" eg if you had something like ...

```
  procedure insert_( col1 varchar2, col2 varchar2  )
  is
    v_errorcode varchar2(64) ;
    v_errormsg  varchar2(128) ;
  begin
    insert into t ( c1, c2 ) values ( col1, col2 ) ; 
  exception
    when others then
      if sqlcode = -1400 or sqlcode = -12899 then
        v_errorcode := sqlcode;
        v_errormsg  := substr( sqlerrm, 1, 128 );
        dbms_output.put_line( v_errorcode || ' ' || v_errormsg  ) ;
      raise;
     end if;
  end insert_ ;
```

... you could get error messages such as these:

```
-1400      ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("MYSCHEMA"."T"."C2") 
-12899     ORA-12899: value too large for column "MYSCHEMA"."T"."C1" (actual: 13, maximum: 10)
```

If this is enough information for you, fine.  However, you also want to see the COMMENTS for the columns.  Although we could get the column names from the SQLERRM strings, it may be more reliable to use user-defined exceptions (as you have hinted).

As a starting point, the following DDL and PACKAGE code may be of use for you. ( see also: [dbfiddle here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=67d408fb8183f2c6fd68af0482516668) )

**Tables:**

```
drop table t cascade constraints ;
drop table errorlog cascade constraints ;

create table t (
  c1 varchar2(10)
, c2 varchar2(64) not null
) ;
comment on column t.c1 is 'this is the column comment for c1';
comment on column t.c2 is 'this is the column comment for c2';

create table errorlog ( 
  when_ timestamp
, msg varchar2(4000) 
) ;
```

**Package spec**

```
create or replace package P is
-- insert into T, throwing exceptions
  procedure insert_( col1 varchar2, col2 varchar2  );
-- use your example SELECT, call the insert_ procedure
  procedure insert_test ;
-- retrieve the column comments from user_col_comments
  function fetch_comment( table_ varchar2, col_ varchar2 ) return varchar2 ;
end P ;
/
```

**Package body**

```
create or replace package body P is

  procedure insert_( col1 varchar2, col2 varchar2  )
  is
    ex_value_too_large exception ;  -- T.c1: varchar2(10)
    ex_insert_null exception ;      -- T.c2: cannot be null
    v_errorcol varchar2(32) := '' ;
    v_comment  varchar2(128) := '' ;
    v_tablename constant varchar2(32) := upper('T') ;
  begin
    if length( col1 ) > 10 then
      v_errorcol := upper('C1') ;
      raise ex_value_too_large ;
    end if;
    if col2 is null then
      v_errorcol := upper('C2') ;
      raise ex_insert_null ;
    end if ;
    insert into t ( c1, c2 ) values ( col1, col2 ) ; 
  exception
    when ex_value_too_large then
      dbms_output.put_line( ' ex_value_too_large @ ' 
        || v_errorcol || ' (' || fetch_comment( v_tablename, v_errorcol ) || ')' );
    when ex_insert_null then
      dbms_output.put_line( ' ex_insert_null @ ' 
        || v_errorcol || ' (' || fetch_comment( v_tablename, v_errorcol ) || ')' );
    when others then
      raise ;

  end insert_ ;

  procedure insert_test
  is
  begin
    for rec_ in (
      select
        case 
          when level = 8 then ( level + 1 ) || 'qqqqqqqqqqqq' 
          else ( level + 2 ) || 'qqq'
        end as col1 
      , case
          when level = 7 then null
          else ( level + 3 ) || 'wwwwwww'
        end as col2
      from dual
      connect by level <= 10
    ) loop
      insert_( rec_.col1, rec_.col2 ) ;
    end loop;
    commit;
   end insert_test;

   function fetch_comment( table_ varchar2, col_ varchar2 ) return varchar2
   is
     v_comment varchar2(4000) ; -- same datatype as in user_tab_comments
   begin
      select comments into v_comment 
      from user_col_comments
      where table_name = table_
        and column_name = col_ ;   
      return v_comment ;
   end fetch_comment ;

end P ;
/
```

For testing the package code, execute the following anonymous block:

```
begin
 P.insert_test ;
end;
/
-- output
ex_insert_null @ C2 (this is the column comment for c2)
ex_value_too_large @ C1 (this is the column comment for c1)

-- Table T contains:
SQL> select * from T;
C1     C2         
3qqq   4wwwwwww   
4qqq   5wwwwwww   
5qqq   6wwwwwww   
6qqq   7wwwwwww   
7qqq   8wwwwwww   
8qqq   9wwwwwww   
11qqq  12wwwwwww  
12qqq  13wwwwwww
```

In the dbfiddle, all output will be written to T and ERRORLOG, respectively.  You can also use dbms_output.put_line (which is commented out in the dbfiddle) if needed.  Notice that the cursor for loop in the insert_test procedure is inefficient (we could use BULK operations).  Also, you need to decide where and how the exceptions are handled.  As mentioned, this example is just a starting point - which will probably need lots of refinements.